# View output doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on the tutorial to display contact details on my page. The code doesn't display the first and last name. Please find the code below.

#### My index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myContactApp">
    <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
            <title>My Contact Application</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Contact App</h1>
        <div data-ng-controller="contactController as ctrl">
            <div data-ng-repeat="con in ctrl.contactArr">
                <span>{{con.name.first+ " "+con.name.last}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### My app.js file

```
var app=angular.module("myContactApp",[]);

app.controller("contactController",contactCtrl);

function contactCtrl(){
this.contactArr = [
    {
      "gender": "male",
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "romain",
        "last": "hoogmoed"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": "1861 jan pieterszoon coenstraat",
        "city": "maasdriel",
        "state": "zeeland",
        "postcode": 69217
      },
      "email": "romain.hoogmoed@example.com",
      "login": {
        "username": "lazyduck408",
        "password": "jokers",
        "salt": "UGtRFz4N",
        "md5": "6d83a8c084731ee73eb5f9398b923183",
        "sha1": "cb21097d8c430f2716538e365447910d90476f6e",
        "sha256": "5a9b09c86195b8d8b01ee219d7d9794e2abb6641a2351850c49c309f1fc204a0"
      },
      "dob": "1983-07-14 07:29:45",
      "registered": "2010-09-24 02:10:42",
      "phone": "(656)-976-4980",
      "cell": "(065)-247-9303",
      "id": {
        "name": "BSN",
        "value": "04242023"
      },
      "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/83.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/83.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/83.jpg"
      },
      "nat": "NL"
    }
  ]


}
```

My page is not showing the first and last name when I run through HTTP-server. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I think you are not including `app.js` properly, is it located in the same place as your HTML page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs like a charm. There is no mistake in it. Please ensure that all ressources (`app.js` & `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js`) are loaded. Open up the network tab in your browser debugger to check this. **Also ensure you cleaned up your browser cache.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myContactApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>My Contact Application</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Contact App</h1>
    <div data-ng-controller="contactController as ctrl">
      <div data-ng-repeat="con in ctrl.contactArr">
        <span>{{con.name.first+ " "+con.name.last}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**--> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6g0jqqg/1/)**

Comment: @bhaskardas updated, I was wrong. Your codes works like a charm. Please compare your local solution with the demo fiddle I added to my answer. Pleaes check the network tab of your browser debugger. Ensure that all ressources (app.js & https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js) are loaded.

Comment: I checked in fiddle its running but not sure why it is not showing in my local environment. I am using HTTP-Server.

Comment: Did you checked the ressources?

Comment: It looks like a server issue. Just check local html shows the outcome but while deployed application doesn't show the output.

Comment: Again, did you checked the ressources? Are they loaded correctly? Please answer my questions.

Comment: Yes checked the network both app.js and angularjs are getting loaded.

Comment: Can you show me the webpage after deploy? Is it available in the web?

Comment: Got the issue its related to browser cache. I opened the application in another browser and it is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Otherwise clear browser cache or else every time you make any change just hard reload that page.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine. Kindly see whether app.js or angular dependency properly loaded or not.
    https://jsfiddle.net/Prasanna15/m3q70umq/
you can check your code.
try to use `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js` this one

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured out it was caching problem. I have resolved the issue. Thanks once again.